# What color precision do modern games use?

Tags: opengl, graphics

What color precision do modern games use to output to the display hardware? Is it still only a byte of precision or is mostly more now?

Do games detect the precision available on the display hardware somehow and use that?

Extra: Okay I mean windows platform, but I didn't think the platform mattered, I thought the hardware mattered.

Comment: Why is the question tagged OpenGL? Could you be more specific about the platform. Do you mean xbox or playstation or windows or iphone or what.

Comment: The "color depth" in modern [desktop] hardware is *normally* 32bits - or 4x8bit channels. This depends on the display configuration, but not necessarily the monitor. The monitor however, especially older LCDs, might only be able to physically display 6bits/channel and thus loses precision. To get a "better" answer you'll need to really narrow down the question.

Comment: Output? Generally 8-bit per-component. But the output is no longer relevant, because they will render the HDR pipeline at somewhere between 10- and 16-bits per-component (32-bit is overkill) and use a tonemap operator to map the HDR back to LDR for display on a traditional monitor.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: You can buy displays that support 10 bits per channel (often used in digital photography and movie production). Digital cinema projectors actually operate at 12 bits per color channel. And medical displays usually support between 12 and 14 bits per channel. The 8 bits per channel consumer displays still use these days are an anachronism. You need at least 11 bits to render grayscale without noticable banding. NVidia is actively pushing for 10 bits per channel displays to become the consumer default.

Comment: Yes, HDMI 1.4 also requires support for 36-bit pixel formats, so TVs will accept such signals. Whether the display actually does anything more than image processing at a higher precision is a different story. 600 Hz PDP displays have 10-bit greyscale @ 60 Hz, making them 30-bit native. With dithering odd sub-fields, Plasma TVs can achieve somewhere between 12- and 15-bit perceived greyscale. There are not a lot of sources that deliver a signal at these higher precisions. Nevertheless, new consoles such as the Xbox One ***can***; whether games actually take advantage of this, I cannot say.